# Need to assign gpg decrypted filename to a variable

Tags: bash, encryption, centos, gnupg, private-key

I'm using below command(non -interactive mode of gpg) to decrypt my file:

```
    gpg --yes  --batch --passphrase=Abcdefgh1$ kbc.text.gpg
```

The file it will decrypt will be kbc.text. Now, in my script I need to assign name of this decrypted file to a variable which I need to use further. For that, I'm using below command:

```
    tmp=gpg --yes  --batch --passphrase=Abcdefgh1$ kbc.text.gpg
```

However, when I run this, I get below error:

```
    script2.sh: line 2: --yes: command not found
```

Any way to implement this and avoid this error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try `tmp=\`gpg --yes  --batch --passphrase=Abcdefgh1$ kbc.text.gpg\``

Comment: @lago ,it's working. Thank you